# Netlify Deployment , Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/SI'

Tags: reactjs, netlify

My app works fine on desktop but when I try to deploy to Netlify I get Module not found: Error:
Do I need to push my Node_modules to GitHub for this to work ? or Netlify is supposed to download all the dependencies from package.json

I appreciate any help, It's first time I'm trying to deploy :) Thanks!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfoliofrontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-typed": "^1.2.0",
    "tsparticles": "^1.30.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production & webpack",
    "build-dev": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const path = require("path");

let mode = "development";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production ") {
    mode = "production";
}

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        clean: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'main.js',
        assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|pdf|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html"
    })],
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

Error on Netlify

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Portfolio.js 14:0-72
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/SI' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
resolve 'react-icons/SI' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /opt/build/repo/src/components/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/build/repo/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /opt/build/repo/node_modules
        existing directory /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons
          using description file: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/package.json (relative path: .)
            using description file: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/package.json (relative path: ./SI)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/SI doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/SI.js doesn't exist
              .json
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/SI.json doesn't exist
              .wasm
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/SI.wasm doesn't exist
              as directory
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/SI doesn't exist
      /opt/build/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/components/App.js 5:0-36 27:17-26
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-35

ERROR in ./src/components/Portfolio.js 15:0-73
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/DI' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
resolve 'react-icons/DI' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /opt/build/repo/src/components/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/build/repo/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /opt/build/repo/node_modules
        existing directory /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons
          using description file: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/package.json (relative path: .)
            using description file: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/package.json (relative path: ./DI)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/DI doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/DI.js doesn't exist
              .json
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/DI.json doesn't exist
              .wasm
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/DI.wasm doesn't exist
              as directory
                /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react-icons/DI doesn't exist
      /opt/build/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/components/App.js 5:0-36 27:17-26
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-35
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the imports from `react-icons/SI` and `react-icons/DI` to `react-icons/si` and `react-icons/di` should work.